# Request for additional documents for faculty position

Tags: faculty-application

I applied for a faculty position about two months ago through an online system for a university. For some reason, I did not receive any email on a request (apparently from the search committee) to upload additional documents. In fact, I had not been asked to upload these documents (teaching evaluation, unofficial transcripts and two more publications) during the initial submission but they just asked for a cover letter, research stat, teaching stat, CV and two publications.

My question is that does it mean I have been shortlisted? I should note that the recommendation letters were (and have not been) asked (yet). They have indicated in the ad that the letters will be asked for the semi-finalists.

Comment: I know it's hard to resist reading into this, but don't.

Comment: Why don't you call *them* to ask?

Comment: @louic: already ask them if I should ask my references to prepare the letters, but they did not give me a clear answer. They said "Thank you for your email. Sorry for any confusion. At this time we don't need any additional documents from you." I think they meant the recommendation letters, not those they had asked for (teaching evaluation, unofficial transcripts and two more publications).

Answer (score 1):

They indicated that they would request reference letters for semi-finalists.

They have not requested your recommendation letters (yet).

Therefore, **you are not a semi-finalist** (yet).

Comment: What should I now consider myself? I think they will not ask everyone for additional documents (just want to be optimistic that I have passed initial filtering).

Comment: @sam it means you are not out of the running yet.

Comment: It could simply mean that they made a mistake in writing the advertisement and didn't ask for all of the materials that they actually wanted.  They could be going back to ask all of the applicants for this additional information.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Yes, this is another possibility!

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Is this very common? Because they actually have updated the ad (after the deadline!) and flagged those documents as - required (in front) and Optional at the end!! So confusing !!

Comment: I've been in the position (as a search committee chair) of requesting additional materials from applicants that were left out of the original advertisement, so I wouldn't be at all surprised if this happened.

Comment: @sam The key word here is "yet".  You are still an applicant under consideration.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: I agree with you, Brian. I appreciate if you can put your comment for this question too: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122459/letter-of-recommendation-before-skype-interview